# alpha level affecting color appearance in pdf vs png plots in R

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'm trying to figure out why colors appear dull when I specify an `alpha` level in `rgb` and save plot as `pdf` (for color transparency less than 1). This does not happen when saved as `png`.

Consider these 3 test figures:

```
# Figure 1
# pdf with alpha specified in rgb
# blues are dull and muted relative to colors in plot window
pdf('test1.pdf', height = 4, width = 4)
plot(1,1, type = 'n')
rect(0, 0, 1, 2, col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 1, alpha = 0.1))
abline(v = 1.3, col = 'blue', lwd = 5)
dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
# Figure 2
# png with alpha specified in rgb
# colors are same as plot window
png('test2.png', height = 288, width = 288)
plot(1, 1, type = 'n')
rect(0, 0, 1, 2, col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 1, alpha = 0.1)))
abline(v = 1.3, col = 'blue', lwd = 5)
dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 2]

```
# Figure 3
# pdf, alpha not specified in rgb
# colors are same as plot window
pdf('test3.pdf', height = 4, width = 4)
plot(1,1, type = 'n')
rect(0, 0, 1, 2, col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 1))
abline(v = 1.3, col = 'blue', lwd = 5)
dev.off()
```

So how can I use transparent colors while keeping the general color scheme as it appears in the console/plot window, also when using `pdf`?

EDIT: I am using Windows 7, and just realized that this does not seem to be an issue on Windows 8 or 10. I did duplicate it on Mac OS 10.7.5 (Lion) however. I also know I was having this problem with whatever version of R I was using back in 2013, as well as this more current version.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.1 abind_1.4-5    CTSim_0.1.7   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5       raster_2.5-8      magrittr_1.5      MASS_7.3-45       splines_3.3.1     fdrtool_1.2.15   
 [7] lattice_0.20-33   FNN_1.1           quadprog_1.5-5    subplex_1.1-6     stringr_1.0.0     plyr_1.8.4       
[13] tools_3.3.1       xts_0.9-7         GUILDS_1.2.1      parallel_3.3.1    grid_3.3.1        gstat_1.1-3      
[19] poilog_0.4        poweRlaw_0.60.3   intervals_0.15.1  numDeriv_2014.2-1 sads_0.3.1        bbmle_1.0.18     
[25] VGAM_1.0-2        sp_1.2-3          stringi_1.1.1     pracma_1.9.3      stats4_3.3.1      spacetime_1.1-5  
[31] zoo_1.7-13
```

Comment: can't replicate on MacOS 10.11.6 or Ubuntu 14.10.  Have you tried `Cairo::CairoPDF()` ?

Comment: With your edit, it seems more likely that the issue is with your PDF viewer than anything else. Try writing a file in Windows 7 and opening it in one of your other systems to see.

Comment: ... or if possible try other PDF viewers on the same system.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. Opening the file in GIMP the colors look fine. Time to abandon Adobe Acrobat Professional 8!